# CSS combinator not working - Differnce of one space?

Tags: css

I have two carousels on a page and need to style them differently. So I have this css combinator to style a child bootstrap element inside an id element...

```
#menuCarousel .carousel { ...
```

Which doesn't work as I expected. However, if I close the space like this...

```
#menuCarousel.carousel { ...
```

the styles are applied. According to W3Schools, there is meant to be a space so I'm thinking I'm doing something else wrong.

What's happening here y'all?

Thanks.

Just in case the html is important:

```
<div id="menuCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
```

Comment: `#id .classname` and `#id.classname` are different selectors; I'm sure W3Schools mention that as well. In your case, the former should be used (as those rules are to be applied only if `#id` element has `classname` in its classList).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off in this case the `.carousel` shouldn't be necessary at all, because IDs **must** be unique and that alone would be sufficient to select the div.

But to get down to your question, a space between CSS selectors will select a descandant element. Removing the space means to select the element with that class.

So `#menuCarousel .carousel { ...` says select all elements with the class `carousel` that are descendants of the element with the ID `#menuCarousel`.

`#menuCarousel.carousel { ...` means select the element that has the ID `menuCarousel` *AND* the class `carousel`.

(And on a side note, don't use w3schools to learn CSS. Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: @raina77ow- True, for specificity cases the added class to ID would make a difference. However in this case, the OP just wants to style one carousel different from another, and the ID alone *should* suffice.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with that last bit.

Comment: Agree on NOT using w3schools website. They have lots of missing information, the reference is incomplete in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

The id= (#) and class= (.) are applying to the same element, so I would think they would have to be combined as `#menuCarousel.carousel`. Otherwise it would be looking for a .carousel *under* a #menuCarousel, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

So a space indicates a nested element like this

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

#parent .child{background-color:blue;}
```

The above example would make the child element blue.

However two selectors without a space is used to select an element using two different selectors on the same element. So

```
#parent.parent{background-color:blue;}
```

Would make the parent element blue in the same way as just #parent